# How to get password reset url in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am porting my data from old system to a new system written in ruby on rails. To get the older users registered I am planning to transfer their old data into new system but I can't transfer their old password so I'm planning  to create a random password and then a password reset link and send them a custom email inviting them to my new system.

Devise provides this:
`user.send_reset_password_instructions`

But this sends a "forgot password" email to user. I just want to get the forgot password url somehow so that I can use that url in my own mail and send it at some later time. I've tried looking up but everywhere they talk about "send_reset_password_instructions" function. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reset password url was formed by `reset_password_token` in `User` model.

So saving the `reset_password_token` is enough to recover `reset password url` later on.

```
reset_password_token = 'XYZ' # Example token
reset_password_url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_user_password_path(reset_password_token: reset_password_token)
```

Comment: So I can manually set that reset_password_token using Devise.friendly_token[0,20]  and get the URL.. That should work right?

Comment: Also there is a method called set_reset_password_token but is protected. You can do something like user.send(:set_reset_password_token) to set a new token.

Comment: Not sure if it's a recent change but what Devise stores in users.reset_password_token is only a digest of the token that is sent into the password reset link. So I think it's actually not possible to recover the original token. The only option is to create a new token and reset it in the db.

Answer (score 5):

Due to security (an attacker could read the link from the database to bypass email verification), what Devise stores in `user.reset_password_token` is only a digest of the token that is sent into the password reset link.

Specifically, in the [`set_reset_password_token` method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/715192a7709a4c02127afb067e66230061b82cf2/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L89-L96), the `enc`oded token is saved to the database, while the `raw` token is returned and then sent in the password reset email.

What you can do is to reset the token yourself and save the raw token somewhere to be used later:

```
raw = user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
```

It's also worth noting that you can customize the devise mailer and provide your own templates. However, in this case, it would also affect the legitimate password reset emails.

Comment: you should be able to generate the path with: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_user_password_path(reset_password_token: user.send
(:set_reset_password_token))`